# Authorize.net returning multiple deliminators

Tags: drupal-6, authorize.net

I am using the Drupal moneyscripts module for recurring payments, everything works as it should, when I am using my Authorize.net sandbox account, but when I enter my live API key login
the module fails. meaning the user is not created in Drupal and the role is not assigned. but the catch is that the transaction does go through to authorize.net and gets approved there.
Only the Drupal side fails (a user is supposed to be created and role assigned)  this works 100% using the authorize.net sandbox account, and the only thing I change is switching from sandbox to live.

Edit: it appears the problem is authorize.net is returning multiple deliminators, support seems to be completely useless in fixing this and it appears to definitely be coming from their end.

I have included response messages from authorize from both and the line of error in the module.  First is the response I get from the live account when Drupal fails second is the response from the sandbox when everything works 100%.

```
Authorize.Net AIM: Payment for Order 66 failed.
<pre>Authnet Object ( [login:Authnet:private] => [transkey:Authnet:private] => [params:Authnet:private] => Array ( [x_delim_data] => TRUE [x_delim_char] => | [x_relay_response] => FALSE [x_url] => FALSE [x_version] => 3.1 [x_method] => CC [x_type] => AUTH_CAPTURE [x_login] => 724Vs5JQht [x_tran_key] => xxxxxxvg5dX [x_card_num] => xxxxxx46 [x_exp_date] => 07/2014 [x_amount] => 0.01 [x_po_num] => [x_tax] => [x_card_code] => 484 [x_invoice_num] => [x_description] => The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month [x_first_name] => Davide [x_last_name] => ededd [x_address] => teststreet [x_city] => New York [x_zip] => 10538 [x_country] => US [x_email] => test@gmail.com [x_cust_id] => 0 [x_customer_ip] => 37.55.241.139 [x_email_customer] => FALSE [x_duplicate_window] => 0 ) [results:Authnet:private] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => [3] => [4] => 1 [5] => [6] => [7] => 1 [8] => [9] => [10] => This transaction has been approved. [11] => [12] => [13] => 228479 [14] => [15] => [16] => Z [17] => [18] => [19] => 5841731972 [20] => [21] => [22] => [23] => [24] => [25] => The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month [26] => [27] => [28] => 0.01 [29] => [30] => [31] => CC [32] => [33] => [34] => auth_capture [35] => [36] => [37] => 0 [38] => [39] => [40] => Davide [41] => [42] => [43] => ededd [44] => [45] => [46] => [47] => [48] => [49] => teststreet [50] => [51] => [52] => New York [53] => [54] => [55] => [56] => [57] => [58] => 10538 [59] => [60] => [61] => US [62] => [63] => [64] => [65] => [66] => [67] => [68] => [69] => [70] => test@gmail.com [71] => [72] => [73] => [74] => [75] => [76] => [77] => [78] => [79] => [80] => [81] => [82] => [83] => [84] => [85] => [86] => [87] => [88] => [89] => [90] => [91] => [92] => [93] => [94] => [95] => [96] => [97] => [98] => [99] => [100] => [101] => [102] => [103] => [104] => [105] => [106] => [107] => [108] => [109] => [110] => [111] => [112] => EA83CEE11EEFD957C634417DE9EEA716 [113] => [114] => [115] => M [116] => [117] => [118] => [119] => [120] => [121] => [122] => [123] => [124] => [125] => [126] => [127] => [128] => [129] => [130] => [131] => [132] => [133] => [134] => [135] => [136] => [137] => [138] => [139] => [140] => [141] => [142] => [143] => [144] => [145] => [146] => [147] => [148] => [149] => [150] => [151] => XXXX6646 [152] => [153] => [154] => MasterCard [155] => [156] => [157] => [158] => [159] => [160] => [161] => [162] => [163] => [164] => [165] => [166] => [167] => [168] => [169] => [170] => [171] => [172] => [173] => [174] => [175] => [176] => [177] => [178] => [179] => [180] => [181] => [182] => [183] => [184] => [185] => [186] => [187] => [188] => [189] => [190] => [191] => [192] => [193] => [194] => [195] => [196] => [197] => [198] => [199] => [200] => [201] => [202] => [203] => [204] => [205] => FALSE [206] => ) [approved:Authnet:private] => [declined:Authnet:private] => [error:Authnet:private] => 1 [test:Authnet:private] => [fields:Authnet:private] => x_delim_data=TRUE&x_delim_char=%7C&x_relay_response=FALSE&x_url=FALSE&x_version=3.1&x_method=CC&x_type=AUTH_CAPTURE&x_login=REMOVEDt&x_tran_key=REMOVEDX&x_card_num=REMOVED&x_exp_date=07%2F2014&x_amount=0.01&x_po_num=&x_tax=&x_card_code=484&x_invoice_num=&x_description=The+Calorie+Myth+-+Monthly+Membership+-+%240.01+every+Month&x_first_name=Davide&x_last_name=ededd&x_address=teststreet&x_city=New+York&x_zip=10538&x_country=US&x_email=test%40gmail.com&x_cust_id=0&x_customer_ip=37.55.241.139&x_email_customer=FALSE&x_duplicate_window=0& [response:Authnet:private] => |1|||1|||1|||This transaction has been approved.|||228479|||Z|||5841731972||||||The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month|||0.01|||CC|||auth_capture|||0|||Davide|||ededd||||||teststreet|||New York||||||10538|||US|||||||||test@gmail.com||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||EA83CEE11EEFD957C634417DE9EEA716|||M||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||XXXX6646|||MasterCard|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FALSE| [url] => https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll ) </pre>
Logged at /srv/bindings/1ea944aacfa249279fb86d3581f0d3b7/code/sites/all/modules/ms_core/gateways/ms_authorizenet/ms_authorizenet.module line 2098
```

this is the array from the debug message that I input on line 2098 the problem seems to be inside inside  ms_authorizenet_charge()  function.  After $aim->proccess.

```
<pre>|1|||1|||1|||This transaction has been approved.|||00000|||Z|||00000||||||The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month|||0.01|||CC|||auth_capture|||0|||Davidee|||Dadadaee||||||teststreet|||New York||||||10538|||US|||||||||test@gmail.com||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||Eremoved0E2BA239F|||M||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||XXXX6646|||MasterCard|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FALSE|</pre><pre>|1|||1|||1|||This transaction has been approved.|||095650|||Z|||5841959304||||||The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month|||0.01|||CC|||auth_capture|||0|||Davidee|||Dadadaee||||||teststreet|||New York||||||10538|||US|||||||||test@gmail.com||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||DD3B1A2B05FD7441BC3E972A0DC966ED|||M||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||XXXX6646|||MasterCard|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FALSE|</pre><pre>|1|||1|||1|||This transaction has been approved.|||102322|||Z|||removed||||||The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month|||0.01|||CC|||auth_capture|||0|||Davidee|||Dadadaee||||||teststreet|||New York||||||10538|||US|||||||||test@gmail.com||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||removed|||M||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||XXXX6646|||MasterCard|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||FALSE|</pre>
```

This is the response from sandbox when everything works 100%

```
Authnet Object
(
    [login:Authnet:private] => 
    [transkey:Authnet:private] => 
    [params:Authnet:private] => Array
        (
            [x_delim_data] => TRUE
            [x_delim_char] => |
            [x_relay_response] => FALSE
            [x_url] => FALSE
            [x_version] => 3.1
            [x_method] => CC
            [x_type] => AUTH_CAPTURE
            [x_login] => 8xxxxxx8
            [x_tran_key] => 4xxxxxxx
            [x_card_num] => 4111111111111111
            [x_exp_date] => 10/2014
            [x_amount] => 0.01
            [x_po_num] => 
            [x_tax] => 
            [x_card_code] => 111
            [x_invoice_num] => 
            [x_description] => The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month
            [x_first_name] => David
            [x_last_name] => Bacham
            [x_address] => sadds
            [x_city] => chicago
            [x_zip] => 15151
            [x_country] => US
            [x_email] => test@gmail.com
            [x_cust_id] => 0
            [x_customer_ip] => 37.55.241.139
            [x_email_customer] => FALSE
        )

    [results:Authnet:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
            [3] => This transaction has been approved.
            [4] => SRFO9I
            [5] => Y
            [6] => 2204549942
            [7] => 
            [8] => The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month
            [9] => 0.01
            [10] => CC
            [11] => auth_capture
            [12] => 0
            [13] => David
            [14] => Bacham
            [15] => 
            [16] => sadds
            [17] => chicago
            [18] => 
            [19] => 15151
            [20] => US
            [21] => 
            [22] => 
            [23] => test@gmail.com
            [24] => 
            [25] => 
            [26] => 
            [27] => 
            [28] => 
            [29] => 
            [30] => 
            [31] => 
            [32] => 
            [33] => 
            [34] => 
            [35] => 
            [36] => 
            [37] => C58xxxxxxxx546B37A
            [38] => P
            [39] => 2
            [40] => 
            [41] => 
            [42] => 
            [43] => 
            [44] => 
            [45] => 
            [46] => 
            [47] => 
            [48] => 
            [49] => 
            [50] => XXXX1111
            [51] => Visa
            [52] => 
            [53] => 
            [54] => 
            [55] => 
            [56] => 
            [57] => 
            [58] => 
            [59] => 
            [60] => 
            [61] => 
            [62] => 
            [63] => 
            [64] => 
            [65] => 
            [66] => 
            [67] => 
            [68] => FALSE
        )

    [approved:Authnet:private] => 1
    [declined:Authnet:private] => 
    [error:Authnet:private] => 
    [test:Authnet:private] => 1
    [fields:Authnet:private] => x_delim_data=TRUE&x_delim_char=%7C&x_relay_response=FALSE&x_url=FALSE&x_version=3.1&x_method=CC&x_type=AUTH_CAPTURE&x_login=8Cxxxx&x_tran_key=xxxxx49vP&x_card_num=4111111111111111&x_exp_date=10%2F2014&x_amount=0.01&x_po_num=&x_tax=&x_card_code=111&x_invoice_num=&x_description=The+Calorie+Myth+-+Monthly+Membership+-+%240.01+every+Month&x_first_name=David&x_last_name=Bacham&x_address=sadds&x_city=chicago&x_zip=15151&x_country=US&x_email=test%40gmail.com&x_cust_id=0&x_customer_ip=37.55.241.139&x_email_customer=FALSE&
    [response:Authnet:private] => 1|1|1|This transaction has been approved.|SRFO9I|Y|2204549942||The Calorie Myth - Monthly Membership - $0.01 every Month|0.01|CC|auth_capture|0|David|Bacham||sadds|chicago||15151|US|||test@gmail.com||||||||||||||C58104D65E4F190912F1D9CCD546B37A|P|2|||||||||||XXXX1111|Visa|||||||||||||||||FALSE
    [url] => https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll
)
```

Here is the code from the module that is throwing the error, I left in the watchdog debug statement so you can see what line 2098 is.

```
  if ($response['approved'] == TRUE) {
    // Insert the Payment to the database for the Free Trial
    $payment = ms_core_new_payment($order->oid, 'ms_authorizenet_cim', 'rec_signup');
    $payment->transaction = $response['data']['txn_id'];
    $payment->currency = 'USD';
    $payment->data = $payment_profile;
    $payment->recurring_schedule = $order->recurring_schedule;

    // Update the address
    $payment->billing_address = array(
      'street' => trim($v['billing_address1']) .'\n'. trim($v['billing_address2']),
      'city' => trim($v['billing_city']),
      'state' => trim($v['billing_state']),
      'zip' => trim($v['billing_zip']),
      'country' => trim($v['billing_country']),
      'phone' => trim($v['billing_phone']),
      );
    $payment->shipping_address = $payment->billing_address;

    // Update the contact details
    $payment->first_name = trim($v['cc_first_name']);
    $payment->last_name = trim($v['cc_last_name']);
    $payment->recurring_id = $order->oid;

    // Add the Payment to the Order
    ms_core_enter_payment($payment, FALSE);

    // Save the CIM profiles
    if (variable_get('ms_authorizenet_cim_profile', FALSE)) {
      $order = ms_core_order_load($order->oid);
      // Create the profile without validating since the AIM is valid
      $cim_result = ms_authorizenet_create_cim_profiles_from_order($order, $v, FALSE);
      if ($cim_result['success']) {
        // Add the payment to the order
        $form_state['values']['ms_oid'] = $order->oid;
        $form_state['values']['ms_order_charged'] = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error') . ': ' . $cim_result['error']);
      }
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error: There was a configuration error in the settings.'));
    }
  }
  else { // The Credit Card was not approved, set an error on the form
    form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error') .': '. $response['message']);
  }
}
else {
  // Check if there is a trial
  $amount = ($order->recurring_schedule['trial_length']) ? $order->recurring_schedule['trial_amount'] : $order->recurring_schedule['main_amount'];

  //my debug message line 2098
    watchdog('ms', '2-V<pre>' . print_r($v , 1) . '</pre>', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
    $response = ms_authorizenet_charge($order, $amount, $v);
     watchdog('ms', '2-ORDER<pre>' . print_r($response , 1) . '</pre>', array(), WATCHDOG_WARNING);



  // Use AIM for the first charge

  if ($response['approved'] == TRUE) {
    // Insert the Payment to the database for the Free Trial
    $payment = ms_core_new_payment($order->oid, 'ms_authorizenet_cim', 'rec_signup');
    $payment->transaction = $response['data']['txn_id'];
    $payment->currency = 'USD';
    $payment->data = $payment_profile;
    $payment->recurring_schedule = $order->recurring_schedule;

    // Update the address
    $payment->billing_address = array(
      'street' => trim($v['billing_address1']) .'\n'. trim($v['billing_address2']),
      'city' => trim($v['billing_city']),
      'state' => trim($v['billing_state']),
      'zip' => trim($v['billing_zip']),
      'country' => trim($v['billing_country']),
      'phone' => trim($v['billing_phone']),
      );
    $payment->shipping_address = $payment->billing_address;
    $payment->recurring_id = $order->oid;

    // Update the contact details
    $payment->first_name = trim($v['cc_first_name']);
    $payment->last_name = trim($v['cc_last_name']);

    // Add the Payment to the Order
    ms_core_enter_payment($payment, FALSE);

    // Save the CIM profiles
    if (variable_get('ms_authorizenet_cim_profile', FALSE)) {
      $order = ms_core_order_load($order->oid);
      // Create the profile without validating since the AIM is valid
      $cim_result = ms_authorizenet_create_cim_profiles_from_order($order, $v, FALSE);
      if ($cim_result['success']) {
        // Add the rec_payment payment to the order
        $payment->type = 'rec_payment';
        $payment->amount = $amount;
        ms_core_enter_payment($payment, FALSE);

        // Add the payment to the order
        $form_state['values']['ms_oid'] = $order->oid;
        $form_state['values']['ms_order_charged'] = TRUE;
      }
      else {
        form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error') . ': ' . $cim_result['error']);
      }
    }
    else {
      form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error: There was a configuration error in the settings.'));
    }
  }
  else { // The Credit Card was not approved, set an error on the form


      form_set_error('ccnumber', t('Error') .': '. $response['message']);
      }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results array from the Live and Sandbox requests are formatted differently.

The approval is supposed to be results[0], and it should be equal to '1' if it was approved. This is how it is in the Sandbox one, but the Live one has a blank value for results[0]. Also, in the Sandbox one, the text 'This transaction has been approved' is in results[3], but the live one has it in results[10].

It appears there is some kind of API version mismatch on what is sent for the Sandbox and the Live.

EDIT: Also, it appears that the delim character might be to blame. It is set to | but the result you are getting had multiple | characters between the values. This is probably the issue that causes the results to be in the wrong spot in the array.

EDIT2: It looks like the individual data items are being enclosed in | and THEN delimited by |. So what should be data1|data2|data3 is being returned as |data1| | |data2| | |data3| (spaces added to show the enclosing and delimiting |'s)

Comment: looks like may be " Field Encapsulation Characte" http://support.authorize.net/authkb/index?page=content&id=A602&actp=LIST thanks for looking at this Leighton http://screencast.com/t/g8dkGcIFwX

Comment: Success it was http://screencast.com/t/g8dkGcIFwX i removed field encapsulation character and it worked!